# GCC, what does -W1 means

Tags: gcc, g++, makefile, cc

I have a legacy Makefile which is using the -W1 argument,
I didn't find any reference to that, I thought it might be a typo, that the '1' is supposed to be 'l'. However, it works...
So, can anyone explain why this line works ?

```
@$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -W1,-soname,$(LIBNAME) -o $(OUTDIR)/$(LIBNAME) $(OBJS)
```

$(CC) is GCC, and the files compiled are C files.
When I tried to compile CPP files using this command, only then I get

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-W1,-soname...
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a typo, and that should be `-Wl` instead.

It's sometimes hard to differ between lower-case L (`l`)  and the digit 1 in some fonts.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Actually it shouldn't work, which makes me a bit curious about the question.